# Ruby Proc that returns numbers and digit strings multiplied by 2 as unchanded type and text strng just returns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, types, type-conversion, proc

I am trying to do my homework and I would like to ask if you can help me to write a Ruby Proc that returns number(Integer,Float,...) and digit strings("22") multiplied by 2 and text string ("sos") just return unchanged. I am trying to do that with unary operator but I doesn't work with Float.

```
def make_double
   proc = Proc.new { |x| ( x.is_a? Integer or x !~ /\D/) ? ((x.to_i)*2).to_s : x }
end
```

Is there a possibility how to write a more complex conditions in proc? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little lost as to what exactly you are expecting this to do.  Maybe a couple of example inputs/outputs might help?  Also, is there a reason you've condensed it all down to one line?  I think the problem is definitely in your x !~/\D/.  The `.to_i` is also going to need to be a `.to_f` from the sound of it.  I think you should check out http://rubular.com/ for the regex but maybe something like `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` ?

Comment: I just need this for example

Comment: p = make_double;;;
p.call(42) -> 84;;;
p.call(42.0) -> 84.0;;;
p.call("42") -> "84.0";;;
p.call("Universe") -> "Universe";;;

and It must be done with Proc

Comment: You can make the proc as complex as you want. It’s standard to use `do..end` syntax if you want to break the proc body across multiple lines.

Comment: @SimonŠtefunko did you notice that your current implementation converts integers to strings, i.e. `proc.call(42)` returns `"84"`, not `84`. Maybe you should fix that bug first.

Answer (score 2):

**Legible**

```
puts '-- do block --'

def make_double
    Proc.new do | x |
        case x
        when Integer, Float then x * 2
        when String
            if x =~ /\d/
            then (x.to_i * 2).to_s
            else x
            end
        else
            "Invalid class #{x.class.name} for x."
        end
    end
end

puts "42 -> #{make_double.call(42)}       #{make_double.call(42).class}"
puts "42.0 -> #{make_double.call(42.0)}   #{make_double.call(42.0).class}"
puts "'42' -> #{make_double.call('42')}     #{make_double.call('42').class}"
puts "'xyz' -> #{make_double.call('xyz')}   #{make_double.call('xyz').class}"
puts "4..8 -> #{make_double.call(4..8)}"
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t_a.rb 
-- do block --
42 -> 84       Integer
42.0 -> 84.0   Float
'42' -> 84     String
'xyz' -> xyz   String
4..8 -> Invalid class Range for x.
```

**Difficult to read**

```
puts '-- brace block --'

def make_double
    Proc.new { | x | x.is_a?(Integer) || x.is_a?(Float) ? x * 2 : \
        x.is_a?(String) ? x =~ /\d/ ? (x.to_i * 2).to_s : x : 'invalid' }
end

puts "42 -> #{make_double.call(42)}       #{make_double.call(42).class}"
puts "42.0 -> #{make_double.call(42.0)}   #{make_double.call(42.0).class}"
puts "'42' -> #{make_double.call('42')}     #{make_double.call('42').class}"
puts "'xyz' -> #{make_double.call('xyz')}   #{make_double.call('xyz').class}"
puts "4..8 -> #{make_double.call(4..8)}"
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 
-- brace block --
42 -> 84       Integer
42.0 -> 84.0   Float
'42' -> 84     String
'xyz' -> xyz   String
4..8 -> invalid
```

Comment: What about `make_double.call("42.5")` not sure if that case matters though.  I think you can save some time too by making everything a string first too.  Something like: `(x.to_s =~ /\d+(?:\.\d+)?/) ? x.to_f*2 : x`

Comment: @user3334690 Right ! As the OP didn't ask, I haven't tested it, and my `if x =~ /\d/` is insufficient. Added a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer takes into account the comment from @user3334690, and corrects wrong results for

```
puts "'42xyz' -> #{make_double.call('42xyz')}   #{make_double.call('42xyz').class}"
puts "'x42y' -> #{make_double.call('x42y')}     #{make_double.call('x42y').class}"
puts "'42.5' -> #{make_double.call('42.5')}    #{make_double.call('42.5').class}"
```

which were

```
'42xyz' -> 84   String
'x42y' -> 0     String
'42.5' -> 84    String
```

**One-liner**

```
puts '-- brace block 2 --'

def make_double
    Proc.new { | x | (x.to_s =~ /\d+(?:\.\d+)?/) ? x.to_f * 2 : x rescue puts "Error" }
end

puts "42 -> #{make_double.call(42)}           #{make_double.call(42).class}"
puts "42.0 -> #{make_double.call(42.0)}         #{make_double.call(42.0).class}"
puts "'42' -> #{make_double.call('42')}         #{make_double.call('42').class}"
puts "'42xyz' -> #{make_double.call('42xyz')}      #{make_double.call('42xyz').class}"
puts "'x42y' -> #{make_double.call('x42y')}        #{make_double.call('x42y').class}"
puts "'42.5' -> #{make_double.call('42.5')}       #{make_double.call('42.5').class}"
puts "'42.5xyz' -> #{make_double.call('42.5xyz')}    #{make_double.call('42.5xyz').class}"
puts "'xyz' -> #{make_double.call('xyz')}         #{make_double.call('xyz').class}"
puts "4..8 -> #{make_double.call(4..8)}"
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t_short2.rb 
-- brace block 2 --
42 -> 84.0           Float
42.0 -> 84.0         Float
'42' -> 84.0         Float
'42xyz' -> 84.0      Float
'x42y' -> 0.0        Float
'42.5' -> 85.0       Float
'42.5xyz' -> 85.0    Float
'xyz' -> xyz         String
Error
4..8 ->
```

Note that all numbers and strings containing numbers are converted to float, and 'x42y' converted to 0.0.

**Keep original class**

Strings mixing numbers and letters are not converted (using anchors ^ and $ in the regexp).

```
puts '-- do block 2 --'

def make_double
    Proc.new do | x |
        case x
        when Integer, Float then x * 2
        when String
            case
            when x =~ /^\d+\.\d+$/ then (x.to_f * 2).to_s
            when x =~ /^\d+$/      then (x.to_i * 2).to_s
            else x
            end
        else
            "Invalid class #{x.class.name} for x."
        end
    end
end

puts "42 -> #{make_double.call(42)}             #{make_double.call(42).class}"
puts "42.0 -> #{make_double.call(42.0)}         #{make_double.call(42.0).class}"
puts "'42' -> #{make_double.call('42')}           #{make_double.call('42').class}"
puts "'42xyz' -> #{make_double.call('42xyz')}     #{make_double.call('42xyz').class}"
puts "'x42y' -> #{make_double.call('x42y')}       #{make_double.call('x42y').class}"
puts "'42.5' -> #{make_double.call('42.5')}       #{make_double.call('42.5').class}"
puts "'42.5xyz' -> #{make_double.call('42.5xyz')} #{make_double.call('42.5xyz').class}"
puts "'xyz' -> #{make_double.call('xyz')}         #{make_double.call('xyz').class}"
puts "4..8 -> #{make_double.call(4..8)}"
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t_b.rb 
-- do block 2 --
42 -> 84             Fixnum
42.0 -> 84.0         Float
'42' -> 84           String
'42xyz' -> 42xyz     String
'x42y' -> x42y       String
'42.5' -> 85.0       String
'42.5xyz' -> 42.5xyz String
'xyz' -> xyz         String
4..8 -> Invalid class Range for x.
```